# Laravel controller won't pass parameter to service

Tags: php, laravel, function, parameters

so i made this input view which input some data, and then some services to process the data, these services are being called from the controller, the problem is when i try to call this particular function `SUPMPFunc($index, $loop, $length)` the controller seems to be not passing the arguments to the service.

This is the too few arguments error is get:

[image: The too few arguments error]

Controller:

```
<?php

class supmpController extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function Store(Request $request)
    {

        $medInput = new MedInput();
        $deviceId = $medInput->MedInput();
        $toolsInput = new ToolsInput();
        $toolsRes = $toolsInput->ToolsInput(request("toolsIndex"));
        $toolsfunctionInput = new ToolsFunctionInput();
        $functionality = $toolsfunctionInput->ToolsFunctionInput(request("checkIndex"));
        $temperature = new TempFunc();
        $humidity = new HumidFUnc();
        $condition = array(
            $temperature->TempFunc(),
            $humidity->HumidFUnc(),
        );
        $electricity = new Electricityinput();
        $elInput = $electricity->ElectricityInput(request("electricIndex"));

        $index = request("tablesupmpindex");
        $loop = request("loopVal");
        $length = request("supmpLength");
        $SUPMP = new SUPMPFunc();
        $result = $SUPMP->SUPMPFunc($index, $loop, $length);
        $analysis = new AnalysisFunc();
        $texttoShow = $analysis->AnalysisFunc();

        $data = array (
            array($deviceId, $texttoShow, $toolsRes, request("loopVal")), //0
            $condition, //1
            $functionality,//2
            $elInput, //3
            $result[0], //4
            $result[1], //5
            $result[2], //6
            $result[3], //7
            $result[4], //8 
            $result[5], //9
            $result[6], //10
        );


        return view('laporan', ['data' => $data]);

    }

}
```

Service:

```
<?php

class SUPMPFunc
{
    public function SUPMPFunc($index, $loop, $length)
    {
        $Avg = new AvgFunc();
        $TINV = new TINVFunc();
        $round = new RoundFunc();
        $stdev = new StdevFunc();
        $budget = new BudgetFunc();
        $drift = new DriftFunc();
        $driftres = $drift->Drift1895040();
        $medInput = new MedInput();
        $deviceId = $medInput->MedInput();
        $resolution = $deviceId[6];

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // everything below is related to calibration value

        $settingsArray = [];
        $valueArray = [];

        for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++)
        {
           array_push($settingsArray, request("table".$index."setVal".$i)); 
        }

        $A1 = request('inVal_A-1');
        $B1 = request('inVal_B-1');
        $C1 = request('inVal_C-1');
        $D1 = request('inVal_D-1');
        $E1 = request('inVal_E-1');
        $F1 = request('inVal_F-1');
        $G1 = request('inVal_G-1');

        $A2 = request('inVal_A-2');
        $B2 = request('inVal_B-2');
        $C2 = request('inVal_C-2');
        $D2 = request('inVal_D-2');
        $E2 = request('inVal_E-2');
        $F2 = request('inVal_F-2');
        $G2 = request('inVal_G-2');

        $A3 = request('inVal_A-3');
        $B3 = request('inVal_B-3');
        $C3 = request('inVal_C-3');
        $D3 = request('inVal_D-3');
        $E3 = request('inVal_E-3');
        $F3 = request('inVal_F-3');
        $G3 = request('inVal_G-3');

        $A4 = request('inVal_A-4');
        $B4 = request('inVal_B-4');
        $C4 = request('inVal_C-4');
        $D4 = request('inVal_D-4');
        $E4 = request('inVal_E-4');
        $F4 = request('inVal_F-4');
        $G4 = request('inVal_G-4');

        $A5 = request('inVal_A-5');
        $B5 = request('inVal_B-5');
        $C5 = request('inVal_C-5');
        $D5 = request('inVal_D-5');
        $E5 = request('inVal_E-5');
        $F5 = request('inVal_F-5');
        $G5 = request('inVal_G-5');

        $A6 = request('inVal_A-6');
        $B6 = request('inVal_B-6');
        $C6 = request('inVal_C-6');
        $D6 = request('inVal_D-6');
        $E6 = request('inVal_E-6');
        $F6 = request('inVal_F-6');
        $G6 = request('inVal_G-6');

        $A7 = request('inVal_A-7');
        $B7 = request('inVal_B-7');
        $C7 = request('inVal_C-7');
        $D7 = request('inVal_D-7');
        $E7 = request('inVal_E-7');
        $F7 = request('inVal_F-7');
        $G7 = request('inVal_G-7');

        $Aval = array(-$A1, -$A2, -$A3, -$A4, -$A5, -$A6, -$A7);
        $Bval = array(-$B1, -$B2, -$B3, -$B4, -$B5, -$B6, -$B7);
        $Dval = array(-$D1, -$D2, -$D3, -$D4, -$D5, -$D6, -$D7);
        $Fval = array(-$F1, -$F2, -$F3, -$F4, -$F5, -$F6, -$F7);
        $Cval = array(-$C1, -$C2, -$C3, -$C4, -$C5, -$C6, -$C7);
        $Eval = array(-$E1, -$E2, -$E3, -$E4, -$E5, -$E6, -$E7);
        $Gval = array(-$G1, -$G2, -$G3, -$G4, -$G5, -$G6, -$G7);

        $koreksiStd = array(
            array(0.0, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0, 0.9, 1.4, 1.3), //koreksistdUp
            array(0.0, 0.7, 0.8, 1.1, 1.1, 1.7, 1.7), //koreksi tdDn
            array(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), //Usertifikat up
            array(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) //Usertifikat dn
        );

        $usertifikat = 0.5;

        for($i = 0; $i < count($koreksiStd[0]); $i++ )
        {
            $Bval[$i] = $Bval[$i] + $koreksiStd[0][$i];
            $Dval[$i] = $Dval[$i] + $koreksiStd[0][$i];
            $Fval[$i] = $Fval[$i] + $koreksiStd[0][$i];
        }

        for($j = 0; $j < count($koreksiStd[1]); $j++ )
        {
            $Cval[$j] = $Cval[$j] + $koreksiStd[1][$j];
            $Eval[$j] = $Eval[$j] + $koreksiStd[1][$j];
            $Gval[$j] = $Gval[$j] + $koreksiStd[1][$j];
        }

        $valVi = 2;
        $valVi2 = 50;
        $valVi3 = 50;
        $dividerD = 2 / sqrt(3);
        $dividerA = 2 / sqrt(6);
        $valURes = $resolution / $dividerA;
        $stdSertifikat = [];
        $UstdSertifikat = [];
        $hysterisis = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($koreksiStd[2]); $i++)
        {
            $stdSertifikat[$i] = $koreksiStd[2][$i];
            array_push($UstdSertifikat, $stdSertifikat[$i] / 2);    
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($hysterisis, abs((($Cval[$i] - $Bval[$i])) + 
                                        ($Eval[$i] - $Dval[$i]) + 
                                        ($Gval[$i] - $Fval[$i])) / 3
            );
        }

        $upAvg = [];
        $dnAvg = [];
        $upKoreksi = [];
        $dnKoreksi = [];
        $upStdev = [];
        $dnStdev = [];
        $upURepeat = [];
        $dnURepeat = [];
        $zeroErr = [];
        $zeroErrU = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($koreksiStd[0]); $i++)
        {
            $array = array(
                $Bval[$i], $Dval[$i], $Fval[$i]
            );

            array_push($upAvg, $round->Roundto($Avg->Average($array), 1));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($koreksiStd[0]); $i++)
        {
            $array = array(
                $Cval[$i], $Eval[$i], $Gval[$i]
            );

            array_push($dnAvg, $round->Roundto($Avg->Average($array), 1));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($upKoreksi, $round->Roundto(($upAvg[$i] - $Aval[$i]), 1));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($dnKoreksi, $round->Roundto(($dnAvg[$i] - $Aval[$i]), 1));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            $array = array(
                $Bval[$i], $Dval[$i], $Fval[$i]
            );

            array_push($upStdev, $stdev->Stdev($array));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            $array = array(
                $Cval[$i], $Eval[$i], $Gval[$i]
            );

            array_push($dnStdev, $stdev->Stdev($array));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($upURepeat, $upStdev[$i] / (2 * sqrt(3)));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($dnURepeat, $dnStdev[$i] / (2 * sqrt(3)));
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($zeroErr, max(abs($Cval[$i] - $Bval[$i]), 
                                    abs($Eval[$i] - $Dval[$i]), 
                                    abs($Gval[$i] - $Fval[$i])
                                ));
        }

        //this one has the same value as u hysterisis column
        for($i = 0; $i < count($Aval); $i++)
        {
            array_push($zeroErrU, $zeroErr[$i] / (2 * (pow(3, 0.5))));
        }

        $KANval = 7.5;

        $UPbudgetua = [];
        $UPbudgetRes = [];
        $UPjumlahuicipow = [];
        $UPjumlahuicivi = [];
        $UPketidakpastianGab = [];
        $UPkebebasanEff = [];
        $UPfaktorCakup = [];
        $UPketidakpastianBen = [];
        $UPfinalRes = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            array_push($UPbudgetua, $upStdev[$i], $zeroErr[$i], $resolution, 0, $stdSertifikat[$i], $hysterisis[$i], ((0.1 * $driftres[0][$i]) / 2));
            $UPbudgetRes[$i] = $budget->Budget($UPbudgetua);
            $UPjumlahuicipow[$i] = $round->Roundto(array_sum($UPbudgetRes[$i][6]), 3);
            $UPjumlahuicivi[$i] = $round->Roundto(array_sum($UPbudgetRes[$i][7]), 3);
            $UPketidakpastianGab[$i] = $round->Roundto(sqrt($UPjumlahuicipow[$i]), 3);
            $UPkebebasanEff[$i] = $round->Roundto((pow($UPketidakpastianGab[$i], 4) / $UPjumlahuicivi[$i]), 3);
            $UPfaktorCakup[$i] = $round->Roundto($TINV->TINV(0.05, $UPkebebasanEff[$i]), 3);
            $UPketidakpastianBen[$i] = $round->Roundto($UPketidakpastianGab[$i] * $UPfaktorCakup[$i], 3);

            if($UPketidakpastianBen[$i] <= $KANval)
            {
                $UPfinalRes[$i] = $KANval;
            }
            else
            {
                $UPfinalRes[$i] = $round->Roundto($UPketidakpastianBen[$i], 1);
            }
            array_splice($UPbudgetua, 0, count($UPbudgetua));
        }

        $DNbudgetua = [];
        $DNbudgetRes = [];
        $DNjumlahuicipow = [];
        $DNjumlahuicivi = [];
        $DNketidakpastianGab = [];
        $DNkebebasanEff = [];
        $DNfaktorCakup = [];
        $DNketidakpastianBen = [];
        $DNfinalRes = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            array_push($DNbudgetua, $dnStdev[$i], $zeroErr[$i], $resolution, 0, $stdSertifikat[$i], $hysterisis[$i], ((0.1 * $driftres[0][$i]) / 2));
            $DNbudgetRes[$i] = $budget->Budget($DNbudgetua);
            $DNjumlahuicipow[$i] = $round->Roundto(array_sum($DNbudgetRes[$i][6]), 3);
            $DNjumlahuicivi[$i] = $round->Roundto(array_sum($DNbudgetRes[$i][7]), 3);
            $DNketidakpastianGab[$i] = $round->Roundto( sqrt($DNjumlahuicipow[$i]), 3);
            $DNkebebasanEff[$i] = $round->Roundto((pow($DNketidakpastianGab[$i], 4) / $DNjumlahuicivi[$i]), 3);
            // $DNfaktorCakDN[$i] = $round->Roundto($round->TINV(0.05, $DNkebebasanEff[$i]), 3);
            $DNfaktorCakup[$i] = $round->Roundto($TINV->TINV(0.05, $DNkebebasanEff[$i]), 3);
            $DNketidakpastianBen[$i] = $round->Roundto($DNketidakpastianGab[$i] * $DNfaktorCakup[$i], 3);

            if($DNketidakpastianBen[$i] <= $KANval)
            {
                $DNfinalRes[$i] = $KANval;
            }
            else
            {
                $DNfinalRes[$i] = $round->Roundto($DNketidakpastianBen[$i], 1);
            }
            array_splice($DNbudgetua, 0, count($DNbudgetua));
        }

        $result = array(
            $Aval,
            $upAvg,
            $dnAvg,
            $upKoreksi,
            $dnKoreksi,
            $UPfinalRes,
            $DNfinalRes,
            $length,
        );

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: and where is `AnalysisFunc` which is where the error is coming from as per the error message? its not the Controller causing the issue, its `AnalysisFunc` class

Comment: @JitheshJose that is not what the error says the problem is

Comment: too few arguments is the problem right ?

Comment: check whether your passing variables got values or not..

Comment: @JitheshJose at least based on what the error message says :) it also doesn't say the error comes from any of the files shown here

Comment: The answer is posted by @Dmitry.I think that's the problem.

Comment: the error is coming from `AnalysisFunc` at line 11 (which is not shown here) ... there might be other issues as well, but this error message says exactly where the error comes from, there is no guessing

Comment: @lagbox you were right, i overlooked the `AnalysisFunc`, must be because lack of focus, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need add parameters in constructor:

```
$index = request("tablesupmpindex");
        $loop = request("loopVal");
        $length = request("supmpLength");
        $SUPMP = new SUPMPFunc($index, $loop, $length); <--edit
```